# Use of count and sum together in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data from a view in ms-sql. I wanted to group the results by **LossTypeExt** and create a new column **Paid Severity** as following:

**Formula to calculate the PaidSeverity:**

```
  paid serverity = sum(totalPiadamount)/distinct count of claims
```

So, my final result should LossTypeExt and PaidSeverity($amt). Any thoughts or help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Sample Data/Table:

```
         ClaimKey   ClaimNum    ClaimOpenDate   TransactionDate TotalLossPaid       LossTypeExt         

         2143672    2143672     2016-11-11      2016-11-16          0.00            Water   
         2143673    2143673     2016-11-15      2016-11-16          5266.00         Wind   
         2143674    2143674     2016-11-15      2016-11-16          151.55          Hail   
         2143675    2143675     2016-12-12      2016-11-16          2656.00         Water   
         2143676    2143676     2016-11-15      2016-11-16          5652.00         AOPD   
         2143677    2143677     2016-11-15      2017-11-16          4545.00         Liability   
         2143678    2143678     2018-18-16      2016-11-16          124.00          Liability 
         2143679    2143679     2018-05-15      2016-11-16          4541.00         AOPD
         2143680    2143680     2017-11-18      2016-11-16          966.00          Fire
```

Expected Data should be like this:

```
         LossTypeExt    PaidSeverity

         Water          $amt
         Wind           $amt
         Fire           $amt
         Hail           $amt    
         AOPD           $amt
         Liability      $amt
```

Query:

```
  select LossTypeExt,
  sum(TotalLossPaid)/claims_cnt as PaidServerity 
 from dbo.vw_Financial_Transactions
cross join
 (select count(distinct claimNum) claims_cnt  from dbo.vw_Financial_Transactions ) as cnt
   group by LossTypeExt
```

Comment: Your expected data defeats the purpose of including your expected data - it would be very helpful if you could replace `$amt` with the actual expected numbers, even if only a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
select LossTypeExt, 
       sum(TotalLossPaid) / claims_cnt as paid serverity 
from table cross join
     (select count(distinct claims) claims_cnt from table) as cnt
group by LossTypeExt;
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a subquery for the count:

```
select LossTypeExt, 
sum(TotalLossPaid)*1.0/ count(distinct claimKey) 
from myTable
group by LossTypeExt;
```